# How to set restful controller scaffold in grails

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I created a restful controller with the command `grails generate-restful-controller Domain`, how to set `scaffold = true` in the controller created, to use the template RestfulController.groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better create REST ready controller, simply by running the command:

```
$ grails generate-controller [Domain Class Name]
```

and make it like this

```
import grails.transaction.*
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.*

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
 class BookController {
…
}
```

Also you can take help from grails documentation

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restfulControllers

hope this helps. Thanks